# Find the volume of the solid bounded below by the circular cone and above the sphere

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates

[image: An image of the problem]
I'm asked to find the volume of the solid bounded below by the circular cone 
$$z= 1.5\sqrt(x^2+y^2) 
$$and above the sphere
$$ x^2+y^2+z^2=7.5z.
$$

I tried to solve this using spherical coordinates, which gave me the bounds 
$$
0 <= \rho <= 7.5 cos(\phi)
$$
$$
0 <= \phi <= arccot(1.5)
$$
$$
0<= \theta <= 2\pi
$$
Are my bounds correct?

Answer (score 0):

[The spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral#Spherical_coordinates):
$$x= \rho \cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)$$
$$y= \rho \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$$
$$z= \rho \cos(\phi)$$
We have 
$$x^2+y^2+z^2\leq7.5z \Rightarrow 0 \leq \rho \leq 7.5 \cos(\phi)$$
$$1.5\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=z \Rightarrow 1.5\sqrt{\rho^2 \sin^2(\phi)}=\rho \cos(\phi)\Leftrightarrow \operatorname{ctg}(\phi)=1.5 $$
We have to find volume of the solid BELOW $z=1.5\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and ABOVE $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq7.5z$, so for azimuthal angle $\phi$ we have 
$$\operatorname{arcctg}(1.5) \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2},$$ and
$$0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi.$$

P.S In case we have to find volume of the solid ABOVE $z=1.5\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and BELOW $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq7.5z$ , then $0 \leq \phi \leq \operatorname{arcctg}(1.5)$.